# Swift: Error al cambiar aspecto a un objeto

Tags: swift, xcode

estoy intentando cambiarle la textura a un objeto, en lugar de darle un color sólido, para eso agregué una imagen .jpg a la carpeta assets.xcassets, para después desde el código darle la textura pero no me aparece la opción para seleccionar dicha textura.
¿Saben si me estaré saltando algún paso para agregar la textura o estoy haciendo algo mal?

```
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let sponge = SCNNode()
    sponge.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
    sponge.position = SCNVector3(-0.2,0,-0.5)
    sponge.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spongeDiffuse


    let rock = SCNNode()
    rock.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
    rock.position = SCNVector3(0.3,0,-0.5)
    rock.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = rockDiffuse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola el problema es que no existe spongeDiffuse ni rockDiffuse como variables.

```
sponge.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "spongeDiffuse")
```

Ojala esto te funcione.

Comment: Sí funciona! Muchas gracias por contestar!

Answer (score 0):

En la imagen 1, muestro las imágenes que agregué en la carpeta assets.xcassets, donde también les cambie el nombre para usarlas desde el código.
En la imagen 2, está el código que utilice para cambiar la textura del objeto, pero al querer poner la textura no me aparece dentro de las opciones por lo que me marca un error.

[image: imagen 1. Imágenes de textura]

[image: imagen 2. Código]